# Characteristic of Integral-domain where $15a=0$ but $3b\neq 0$.

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain. Let $a,b \in R$. Assume that a and b both not zeros,
$15a = 0$ and $3b \neq 0$ group. What can you say about the characteristic of $R$?

Comment: Thank you for editing it. It looks much better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0 = 15a = 5a\cdot 3a$, and $R$ is an integral domain, so $3a=0$ or $5a=0$. Now use the integral domain property again.

Can you now deduce what the characteristic is? (Recall, it cannot be composite and we know $3b \neq 0$).

Comment: Since Char(R) is the smallest positive integer n such that n·a = 0 for all a ∈ R and we have R a commutative ring that have no zero divisors (integral domain). then since 3b≠0, it implies that 5a=0 only if a=0 which makes Char(R)= zero. But a≠0 !!
I am really lost here !

Comment: No. $a\neq 0$, so $3a=0 \Rightarrow 3 = 0$, but we know this isn't the case since $3b\neq0$, so $3a\neq 0$. Hence we know that $5a=0$, and since $a\neq 0$, $5=0$...

Comment: I figured that out the minute I posted my comment. Could you explain what do you mean by 5=0 here please !

Comment: Exactly what is written (if you assume $5 = \sum_{i=1}^5 1$). I'm assuming you know that if $char\, R = p>0$, then $p$ is the least integer such that $\sum_{i=1}^p 1 =0$.

Comment: You can deduce this. Why is 5 the *least* positive integer $p$ with $\sum_{i=1}^p 1 =0$?

Comment: Thank a million. I really hate my book since it does not give any examples to makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,\  0 = (15a)b = 5(3b)a\ $ and $\ (3b)a\ne 0\,\Rightarrow\,\ldots = 0$